# Javascript: Promise.all doesn't seem to be resolving

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to map over some RSS feeds using `feedparser-promised`, but my call to `Promise.all()` isn't returning anything. (use of `var` is from my REPL, which doesn't support `const` or `let`)

```
var feedparser = require('feedparser-promised');
var R = require('ramda');
var URLS = ['http://feeds.gawker.com/gizmodo/full',
            'http://kotaku.com/vip.xml',
           'http://www.medievalhistories.com/feed/'];

var getAllFeeds = (urls) => {
    promises = R.map(feedparser.parse, urls);
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then((itemArrs) => itemArrs)
        .catch((err) => {throw new Error(err)});
}

var x = getAllFeeds(URLS);
console.log(x);
```

`x` comes back as `undefined`.  If I do a log on `promises`, it shows as an array of Promises, as expected.  What am I missing?

Comment: Even if I replace the `.then` with `.then((itemArrs) => console.log(itemArrs))`, the itemArrs never get logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is undefined because `getAllFeeds` is a [arrow function with statement body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that does not explicitly `return`.

You should return the `Promise.all` promise and consume the results in `then`/`catch` handlers:

```
var getAllFeeds = (urls) => {
    var promises = R.map(feedparser.parse, urls);
    return Promise.all(promises)
}

getAllFeeds(URLS)
  .then(items => {
    console.log(items);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
```

Comment: Still looks like I'm missing something; nothing ends up logging out.

Comment: @KevinWhitaker: Maybe you're got a rejection

Comment: Looks like my REPL was acting up.  @joews answer works